# Bind to ControlTemplate element from outside of the control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In my WPF Window I need to bind to the value from inside of a ControlTemplate.

Here's my code (maximally simplified):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
              <Border Name="MyBorder" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Green" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
      <Button Name="MyButtonInstance" />
      <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="200" 
                 Fill="{Binding ????}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I would like to bind **Fill** property of **MyRectangle** to a value that is property of **MyBorder** (**Background**) - which is part of Button ControlTemplate. Is it possible?

I have tried

```
Fill="{Binding ElementName=MyBorder, Path=Background}"
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot bind that way. What you can do is to have a common resource which is supplied to both border and rectangle. refer below code.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SameKey" 
               Color="Green"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="MyBorder" Height="100" Width="100" Background="{StaticResource SameKey}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="MyButtonInstance" />
        <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="200" 
             Fill="{StaticResource SameKey}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem is that in my real case the ControlTemplate property can change at runtime (it is actually ActualHeight property)... I cannot use static value.

Comment: try use DynamicResource

Comment: @dzb That doesn't make much sense, because there might be multiple instance of the templated Button, i.e. multiple Borders. The ActualHeight of which Border instance would you then bind to?

Comment: @Clemens In my case there will be only one control using the ControlTemplate. Is there any way to get property value from template element?

Comment: Why not use the ActualWidth of the Button? Should be the same value as that of the Border inside its Template.